# Log files not showing access to a jpeg, but the access happened

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, grep, ubuntu-14.04

I put a jpeg on a webpage, now I want to see who did access it. I know that at least 40 people must have seen it according to a counter.
I looked through /var/www/vhosts with `grep jpeg.jpg -r /var/www/vhosts`yet I could only find a few accesses by my own ip.

Where do I find the logs that show who accessed the jpg?

Comment: I think of you check the ACCESS LOG  there should be entries in there for every request.  https://www.keycdn.com/support/apache-access-log

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html